# How return a string from a ruby hash

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I have this hash:

```
input = [
  { name: 'João dos Santos Neto',
  cpf: '00011122233',
  state: 'Rio de Janeiro',
  value: '12345' },
  { name: 'Maria da Silva Nunes',
  cpf: '99988877766',
  state: 'São Paulo',
  value: '98765' }
]

def solution(input)
  # return a string
end
```

How do I convert this hash into a string of multiple lines, where each value of this hash becomes a line in the string.

Example:

```
solution(input) == "João dos Santos Neto, 00011122233, Rio de Janeiro, 12345 \n
                   Maria da Silva Nunes, 99988877766, São Paulo, 98765"
```

Comment: "How do I convert this hash […]" – A good way to start would be to write some code that does what you want. f you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short [mre] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My one-liner:

```
def solution(input)
    input.map { |person| person.values.join(", ") }.join("\n")
end
```